# How is it that you play Overwatch for free for a limited time?

Tags: overwatch

On Australian Pay TV (i'm with Austar) there's been an ad running showing clips of the animated Overwatch character episodes advertising that you can play Overwatch for free for a limited time (i don't recall the period but it's this month) and at the end of the ad showing the PS4 and X-Box One games.

Now i can't really see Electronics Boutique (EB), Target, Big W, KMart, JB Hifi and any other small retailer banding together to give out free copies of the games and from my understanding the only thing you pay in-game is currency to buy skins, poses and voices.

So how is it you play Overwatch for free for a limited time?

Comment: Digital download, naturally. Check out http://playoverwatch.com/ for instructions.

Comment: That's the answer, @Unionhawk. Might as well post it.

Comment: Also, I don't think there are any microtransactions in Overwatch. The in-game currency is earned in-game.

Comment: There's only one microtransation, but it's to buy more loot boxes (which converts into currency by drop or duplicate items)

Comment: @Unionhawk i see, the ad on TV never said it applied to only the digital versions and only showed the physical covers so i was left to assume that if i went into EB to get a physical copy of the game (as i will always try first) it would be in some way free and i always thought after the initial cost to buy it it was free

Comment: @DCShannon i know there's microtransations in it because it has been discussed that a game which you buy still has them (and it's not DLC). but maybe i'm getting mixed up and it's the crates/boxes you can buy with real money and thinking that was just with CS:GO

Comment: @Memor-X I stand corrected. You can indeed buy loot boxes: https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/overwatch-loot-box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In exactly the same way we played during the open beta.

[The ad you're seeing is for consoles only.](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20243911) Should you have one of the consoles (XB1 with Xbox Live Gold or PS4) you will be able to download the game from the Store starting tomorrow, for the duration of the weekend and try it out.

Comment: Should probably add a link. Unionhawk has one in his comment up there. Explicit dates would help.

Comment: Note that "This weekend" runs from September 9th to the 12th.